# 10.10 updated and my internal camera not working

Tags: macos, camera

I have just updated my 2013 MacBook Pro 13 inch with 10.10 Yosemite, but now I can't webcast.

How do I turn the camera back on?

Comment: Does the camera work if you go to PhotoBooth?

Comment: Yes it works in Photo Booth.  Apple's answer is a Genius Bar appt. on 11th November

Answer (score 7):

Hi I had the exact same problem. Played around with terminal and figured out a way to reset the camera. Just open terminal, paste this in to it, and then press <kbd>Return</kbd>:

```
sudo killall VDCAssistant
```

Comment: That helped me too. But what exactly is this command do? What is `VDCAssistant`?
Some info can be found [here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/12/27/fix-there-is-no-connected-camera-error-mac/).

Comment: Facing the same issue. For me the VDCAssistant is not running at all. Any suggestion?

Comment: It didn't work via terminal, but force quitting VDCAssistant via Activity Monitor did. Basically the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint :-). It allowed me to skype properly with a great friend tonight.

Comment: Can the same command resolve issues related to apps trying to access the built-in microphone? Does anyone know this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug. I experience the same problem after upgrading to 10.10.1. See [Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6611178) for some ideas to solve it (resetting SMC). But since the proposed solutions are not consistently helping to solve the problem, I really suspect a driver problem. My System Profiler is showing "No video capture devices were found." Alternatively you could try to connect an external USB camera.